# Installing door in 2x6 wall (drywall only on 1 side)

Tags: doors, basement-refinishing

Renovating my basement and I have 3 doors to install. Planning to install 2 prehung doors in the first 2 locations (2x4 walls with drywall on both sides).

Not sure what to do about the 3rd. It will go in a **2x6** wall leading to a workshop that will remain unfinished (**no drywall**). I want the door to swing **into** this space. Is this a case where I need to purchase a slab door and do the framing myself?

I know you can install jamb extensions for a 2x6 wall. But if I go with the prehung, should I just fasten the casing to the unfinished studs in the workshop?

Comment: You can certainly attach the prehung frame level with the workshop side of the wall, framed appropriately; then it's just a matter of how much you care about making the trim "pretty".

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Sounds like a good answer. (But I thought you only did windows?)

Comment: Thanks @bib. Turns out I'll even clean oven doors if there's money in it...

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate What I was suggesting is moving your comments to an actual answer. Comments eventually get deleted.

Comment: @bib -- I didn't realize comments got discarded over time. I hadn't really put as much content as usual into the answer, so I figured I'd just make it a comment... and now I'm going to go delete my original comment, which will make the entire conversation look odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #3, I'd buy a prehung door with a 6-1/2" jamb (normal for 2x6 construction) and set the jamb 1/2" proud into the workshop. This makes it easy to add drywall to the workshop in the future if desired. (And personally, I'd skip casing entirely since you're at bare studs in the workshop. If you had to have casing, I'd butt it against the jamb instead of overlap it.)

Comment with any questions...